# mycode.exe: *** fatal error - console device allocation failure - too many consoles in use, max consoles is 32

Tags: g++

**Code File:** mycode.c

**Compiler:** C:\cygwin64\bin\g++.exe

**Compile Command:** g++ -o mycode mycode.c

**Output File:** mycode.exe

**mycode.exe Execution Time Approx:** 1 Hour

**Os:** Windows 10

**My Work Need:** Run 100 cme.exe different parallel windows terminal and run mycode.exe on each terminal

**Problem Statement:** After 32 windows running, at 33rd window, i am getting error *"mycode.exe: *** fatal error - console device allocation failure - too many consoles in use, max consoles is 32"*

**Need your expert help** on "how to recover from this error?" and run mycode.exe 100 times parallel.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** change compiler to https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/

**Compile Command:** C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\c++ -o mycode mycode.c

**Observation:** i am able to run 100 parallel mycode.exe